# SumIf function in Excel returning zero

Tags: sumifs

So essentially, I am attempting to make use of the following function:

```
=SUMIF('Investment Database'!C3:K500,"'Investment Database'!D3:D500=D3",'Investment Database'!K3:K500)
```

Essentially, I want it to scan `Column D` in my Investment Database and then, for those values in `Column D` that correspond to the value contained in `D3` in my Client Report (the report I'm working in), I want to sum the corresponding values in `Column K` in my Investment Database.

Comment: I think you have the criteria argument somewhat confused, check out this : https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!